# How do I use Zapier's StoreClient to set and retrieve a single value?

Tags: javascript, promise, zapier

Following the documentation, I am using this in my JS:

```
var store = StoreClient('my secret');
store.set('active', true);
var status = store.get('active');
```

The variable `status` never has a value. I'm clearly not using the library correctly.

For context, this is inside a `switch` statement that does something like this for many of the cases, where some of them need to set or get a value from the StoreClient.

[The documentation](https://zapier.com/help/code/#storeclient-javascript) uses this example:

```
var store = StoreClient('your secret here');
store
  .set('hello', 'world')
  .then(function() {
    return store.get('hello');
  })
  .then(function(value) {
    // value === 'world'
    return store.delete('hello');
  })
  .then(function() {
    callback();
  })
  .catch(callback);
```

Because I'm on the amateur side, I'm not super familiar with promises. In that example, it's unclear to me which parts of the are required in order to [a] set, and eventually, [b] get a value. I suggest including an example that doesn't have set/get/delete combined into one.

I tried this:

```
var store = StoreClient('my secret');
store
  .set('active', true)
  .then(function() {
    return store.get('active');
  })
  .then(function() {
    callback();
  })
  .catch(callback);
```

... but then I get an error that there is no  `output` variable, even though I haven't touched the `output` variable at the bottom of the script.

Comment: Using `callback` with promises makes this a horrible example indeed. But please link the documentation you are referring to so that we can see the full code.

Comment: @Bergi added documentation link

Answer (score 0):

David from Zapier's Platform team here.

Sorry about the confusion in the docs. I'll give you a quick answer on how to fix your code and a long one as to why. In the meantime, I'll make a note to update the docs with more sensical examples.

### Short

Two big things:

A. Promises pick whatever was returned in the last function. If you don't bring them along, they're lost. Your code should read:

```
.then(function(storedVal) { // <- that variable is missing in your code
  console.log('stored val is', storedVal);
})
```

B. You need to provide a value to the second argument of `callback`. There's a better example [here](https://zapier.com/help/code/#store-state).

```
.then(function(storedVal) {
  callback(null, {active: storedVal});
})
```

### Long

Here's some of the nitty gritty on how to make all Zapier code work great.

#### Callback

Your code runs inside AWS Lambda, which always needs to know when you're finished. It executes all of your code in a special function with a certain set of arguments. The pertinent one here is `callback`, a function that you can call when you're ready to exit (or have an error). You can read more about that setup [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html#nodejs-prog-model-handler-callback).

Like most node callbacks, the `callback` has the function signature `callback (error, result)`. To throw an error, you pass something in the first spot:

```
callback({msg: 'thing went wrong'});
```

To pass a result, use the second (and nothing in the first)

```
callback(null, {myData: 4});
```

So, not passing anything there is why the zap result isn't seeing any data.

#### Promises

In general, callbacks suck and are confusing to work with, so we designed `StoreClient` to return promises. There's a lot of materials about promises online so I won't go into the details here. The important thing is that whatever gets returned from a promise's function is the argument in the next one. For example:

```
Promise.resolve(1)
  .then(function(val) {
    // val === 1
    return Promise.resolve(val + 1)
  })
  .then(function(val) {
    // val === 2
  })
```

There's a more practical example in [these docs](https://zapier.com/help/code/#store-state):

```
var store = StoreClient('your secret here');
var outCount;
store
  .get('some counter')
  .then(function(count) {
    count = (count || 0) + 1;
    outCount = count;
    return store.set('some counter', count);
  })
  .then(function() {
    callback(null, {'the count': outCount});
  })
  .catch(callback);
```

Hopefully that clears things up a bit!

Also, if you want to give Python a try, you can do the same code, but much simpler ([example here](https://zapier.com/help/code-python/#store-state)).

Either way, let us know if there's anything else we can do to help!

Comment: To avoid possibly having called `callback` twice when it throws, it's [better style](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) to use `.then(outCount => callback(null, {'the count': outCount}), err => callback(err))`.